# Permutation and Combinations with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Hallo :) This is a question about permutations but with conditions.

2 boys and 4 girls are to be arranged in a straight line.
In how many ways can this be done if the two boys must be separated? (The order matters)

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share those? Regards

Answer (score 2):

The girls can be arranged in $4!$ ways. They determine $5$ "gaps," of which $3$  are real gaps between the girls, and the other $2$ are end "gaps." The oldest boy can be inserted into any of these gaps. For each choice, there are $4$ gaps for the other boy, for a total of $(5)(4)(4!)$. The idea obviously generalizes.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way:

How many ways are there of arranging all six people without restriction?

How many arrangements have the two boys together?

Therefore how many arrangements have the two boys separated?

Answer (score 1):

Total number of ways of arranging the people = 6!

Cases when boys are together:

(2B) G G G G

G (2B) G G G

G G (2B) G G

G G G (2B) G

G G G G (2B)

Each of the above combinations can be arranged in 2 * 4! ways.
(The factor of 2 is accommodated since the boys themselves could be interchanged, as they are on a straight line.)

Number of ways to separate the boys = (6! - (2 * 5 * 4!)) = 5! * (6 - 2) = 480